# InApp not working with iOs 5.1.1

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

my app has an inApp purchase which is working fine with my ipad having iOS 5.0.

Now the same build when tested with iOS 5.1.1 giving error in inApp Purchase "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". While debugging i am getting the product list succesfully but getting error when i try to purchase that product...

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
```

Is anybody facing this type of error for inApp purchase? Any suggestion will be of great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for me:-

Go to Setting--->General--->Reset--->Reset All Setting, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're using paymentWithProductIdentifier: which is deprecated in iOS 5.0, maybe that's the problem.
Try using :paymentWithProduct: instead.

"paymentWithProductIdentifier:
Returns a new payment with the specified product identifier. (Deprecated in iOS 5.0.)" http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/StoreKit_Collection.pdf

Comment: I will try with paymentWithProduct: but my app is working fine with iOS 5.1.1 on iPad 1, its not working only in iPad 2 onwards.